# Permanent open GUI session on remote computer (Ubuntu Server 12.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vnc, remote-access, x11-forwarding

I'm looking for this (using Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 and Ubuntu Server 12.04):

- I need 1 machine (A) with an nonstop open session, because it has several programs which I need to be running constantly.
- I need to access remotely to that machine (A) from another machine (B).
- I can't work just with command-line commands, because many of the programs running on A have graphical interfaces, and I need to see them to understand the results, know what to do, etc.
- I don't want machine A to display anything but an empty promt or a login screen.

So far, I have used openssh-server and client, vnc4server on machine A and Reminna as client on machine B.

Everything works perfectly, but I need the session not being shown on server screen, or hide it somehow.

Is it possible?

Please excuse my english; it's not my native language.

EDITED:

I've followed the steps shown on http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html

So far, I get to launch gnome-session, but it just overlaps with my local also gnome desktop; doesn't appears inside a window-container.

I keep on trying with different combinations of software avaible to make it, but not getting the needed results so far :(

I promise to post the solution when I'll get it, but in the meanwhile, any help is more than wellcomed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for X11 forwarding:
http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html

Comment: May well be a good solution; I'm adding a new "EDIT" on the question to try to give more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about launching a new, second X session and accessing that X session using remote desktop software like VNC or TeamViewer? The new X session wouldn't be displayed on the computer monitor.

The following is quoted from "[How to start a second X session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85384/17214)":

> ```
> $ startx -- :1
> ```
>
> Note that you need to be on a text console. If you do this from an X
>   session, you may not be authorized. First Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to a
>   text console and log in there.
>
> Press Ctrl+Alt+F7 and Ctrl+Alt+F8 to switch between the X sessions
>   (the F key numbers may vary depending on your distribution).
>
> If you want more control you can add more options to the command like
>   so:
>
> ```
> $ startx gnome-session -- :1 vt8
> ```
>
> This will start up gnome-session on display :1 and run it on virtual
>   console 8 (Ctrl+Alt+F8).

Now you should be able to launch your remote desktop server in the new X session like this:

```
DISPLAY=:1 teamviewer
```

In the case of TeamViewer, you might have to access the physical computer, enter the new X session (`Ctrl+Alt+F8`) and configure the remote desktop server. This probably isn't the case with VNC, but I really have no experience with it. If you really want to use TeamViewer or SplashTop, you might have to configure and connect via VNC first, then set up the other remote desktop server software through their GUIs.